# Shell script file watcher concurrency

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have the following script (shell script running on OEL5.6) that is currently scheduled via cron to pick files up from given directories (specified in a database table) and to call a processing script on them on a directory & filemask basis. The script works fine at the moment but with this implementation if one folder has a large amount of files to process even if all other folders complete the script won't exit until that one has, which means files landing in the other folders won't be picked up until the next run. I'd like to use a similar approach to this but to have it constantly checking folders for new files instead of sequentially running through all folders once and then exiting so it would run as more of a daemon constantly in the background. Any ideas rather than wrapping this in a `while true` loop? I've filtered out a bit of code from this example to keep it short.

```
readonly HOME_DIR="$(cd $(dirname $0)/;echo $PWD)"
export LOCK_DIR="/tmp/lock_folder"

check_lock() {
    # Try and create the $LOCK_DIR lock directory. Exit script if failure.
    # Do some checks to make sure the script is actually running and hasn't just failed and left a lock dir.
}

main(){
    # Check to see if there's already an instance of the watcher running.
    check_lock

    # when the watcher script exits remove the lock directory for the next run
    trap 'rm -r $LOCK_DIR;' EXIT

    # Pull folder and file details into a csv file from the database -> $FEEDS_FILE

    # Loop through all the files in given folders
    while IFS="," read feed_name feed_directory file_mask
    do

        # Count the number of files to process using the  directory and file mask
        num_files=$(find $feed_directory/$file_mask -mmin +5 -type f 2> /dev/null | wc -l 2> /dev/null)
        if [[ $num_files < 1 ]]; then
            # There's no files older than 5 mins to pickup here. Move on to next folder.
            continue 
        fi

        # Files found! Try and create a new feed_name lock dir. This should always pass first loop. 
        if mkdir $LOCK_DIR/$feed_name 2>/dev/null; then 
            $HOME_DIR/another_script.sh "$feed_name" "$feed_directory" "$file_mask" & # Call some script to do processing. This script removes it's child lock dir when done. 
        else
            log.sh "Watcher still running" f
            continue
        fi

        # If the amount of processes running as indicated by child lock dirs present in $LOCK_DIR is greater than or equal to the max allowed then wait before re-trying another.
        while [ $(find $LOCK_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -path $LOCK_DIR | wc -l) -ge 5 ]; do
            sleep 10
        done

    done < $FEEDS_FILE

    # Now all folders have been processed make sure that this script doesn't exit until all child scripts have completed (and removed their lock dirs).
    while [ $(find $LOCK_DIR -type d | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; do
        sleep 10
    done

    exit 0
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: The OS is OEL 5.6

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to use `inotifywait` from `inotify-tools` to monitor the directories for changes. This is more efficient than constantly scanning the directories for changes. Something like that

```
inotifywait -m -r -e create,modify,move,delete /dir1 /dir2 |
    while IFS= read -r event; do
        # parse $event, act accordingly
    done
```

Comment: The current process is powered by a config table which looks like : feed_name, directory, filemask, ... . Using inotifywait would I still be able to use this approach? Each directory and filemask combo has different params applied to it which are passed to the "another_script.sh" in my example taken from the database table.

Comment: `inotifywait` will let you know for modification in all directories. If you need to handle those directories differently, you can do that after you've received an notification, using an `if-then-else` in bash. Alternatively, you could launch several different watchers in multiple processes.